# VBA paste to the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to get my zero values to copy and paste to the same row. If I have a range of them from G4:G8, they paste to C1:C4, how can I get them to go directly over with out starting at the beginning of C.

```
Sub CopyZeroData()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, x As Long, y As Long, N As Long, rng As Range

Set sh1 = Sheets("Ecars")
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    y = 1

    For x = 1 To N
        Set rng = sh1.Cells(x, "G")
            If rng.Value = 0# Then
                rng.Copy sh1.Cells(y, "C")
                y = y + 1
            End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change `rng.Copy sh1.Cells(y, "C")` to`rng.Copy sh1.Cells(x, "C")`?

Comment: thanks findwindow, I completely looked over that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset as well in your code. Your question, it looks like you are looping through column G, if it equals zero, you want column c to equal zero.

```
Sub If_Zero()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, N As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Ecars")
    With sh1
        N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("G1:G" & N)
    End With
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = 0 Then c.Offset(0, -4) = c
    Next c

End Sub
```